# Characterizing a distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, gamma-distribution

I have a set of words which in a given year has a frequency of occurrence k. I can observe that these words follow frequencies k1, k2, k3,....kn in the following year.

If I have some data in the form of k1 -k, k2-k, k3-k...kn-k, is there a method to find the process which generated this variation?

Comment: The data cannot be gamma-distributed. The values are integers (i.e. the variable is discrete, not continuous).

Comment: Thank you. Could you suggest an alternate approach to find the distribution which could have generated these observations?

Comment: It's unlikely real data would be generated by any simple distribution. You may be able to get an adequate approximation for one purpose or another (a negative binomial will be quite a reasonable choice for this by the look), but don't make the mistake of believing your models are generally anything more than approximations. Many tasks can be easily accomplished without choosing a distribution. Why do you need a distributional model?

Comment: Lets say n words has a frequency k in my corpus in a year and those words have a frequency k' in the following year. Then, (k' - k) is the list of values in my observations. 
I am trying to see if there is a pattern that can define these variations. I am not sure what is the right approach to characterize this - a distribution model is what I thought of as an approach.  Thank you for the suggestion on negative binomial distribution. I will look into it. Please let me know if I'm making a mistake in my approach here.

Comment: I don't follow your description and I don't follow what you mean by "a pattern that can define these variations" -- what would you be trying to do with a model? What would you use it for? Please revise your question so that it doesn't talk about fitting a gamma distribution and includes some of the additional details (more fully explained). The [fit of a negative binomial to your data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cX6A.png)  looks quite good (except that two values at 21 is surprising) but it's not at all clear you need a model.

Comment: I will be using the model to predict the probability that a given word which has a frequency k in a year will have a frequency k' in the next year. 
I was assuming that if there is a distribution which (k - k') follows, I would be able to make this prediction.

Comment: This requirement sounds potentially more complicated than simply fitting a distribution to the counts; you need some assumptions about how things are related over time.

Comment: I fear your question is probably now overly broad, perhaps even more difficult to answer than before; I had not intended that you delete *all* the previous context, including even the data -- just the part asking about a gamma fit when the data were counts.

Comment: Oops. I am sorry about that, Glen. This is part of my ongoing research work and I am not at liberty to add a lot of details. I will update the question once again soon. Thank you for helping me out again.